# Jquery toggle only showing, not hiding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to toggle showing something on my page, but it will show up but won't hide after I click the button again. When I click the button, the part I want to show shows up just fine, but when I click it again, it does not hide. Here is my code.

```
<head>
    <script src="JQ.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".thingy").hide();
            $(".show_button").click(function() {
                $(".thingy").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="show_button_box">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="show_button" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;position:relative;top:-8px;left:15px;">Show</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

/* My php is here*/

```
    echo"
    <div class='thingy' onclick='$(\"thingy\").hide();'>
    <div id=\"container\">
    <div class=\"menu\">
    <div class=\"button\" onclick=\"loadpage('bots','Bot Creator');\"><b style='color:black'>Create Bot</b></div><br /><br />
    <div class=\"button\" onclick=\"loadpage('close','Emergancy Close Client');\" style=\"background-color:red;color:black;font-weight:bold;border-radius:6px;\">Emergency Close.</div><br /><br />
    <div class=\"button\" onclick=\"loadpage('news','Spark News.');\" style=\"background-color:lime;color:black;font-weight:bold;border-radius:6px;\"   >Spark News.</div></div><br /><br />
    <div id=\"addedcontent\">       
    <div id=\"b-header\">            header                    </div>       
    <div id=\"b-content\">            content        </div>    </div></div></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your php

you have missed a `.` in css selector

`<div class='thingy' onclick='$(\".thingy\").hide();'>`

Comment: That works but when I try to click a button on the box it closes the box, how can I make it so I click show a second time and the box closes?

Comment: which did you click on? the `<div class='thingy'></div>'` or the `<div class='show_button'></div>`. Are they in the same HTML page?

Comment: when I click on the show_button, and yes they are int he same page.

Comment: not easy to see what's wrong, need actual code or working page to investigate further